# Cannot see computer files in Anaconda's Jupyter

Tags: python, file, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, desktop

I have downloaded Anaconda with the hopes of using Jupyter for python. A colleague of mine had it working so that when it opened he was able to open up any file on his computer, mine does not give me that option. So when I go to open a file I am not able to see the majority of my computer drives or folders (including desktop). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Change the blue part (rom Step1) to "jupyter notebook" and click enter, it will open path on jupyter notebook.
[Step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnBzX.png) [Step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lszFv.png)